# Insertion failed when converting the nvarchar value to data type int in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I have a XML transposing rows into column query. I am trying to insert the data to a table that is created dynamically. However, I am getting error saying conversion failed when converting nvarchar value to data type int when I execute '@query'

This is my current code:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @cols1 NVARCHAR(MAX), @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @cols = STUFF(
             (
                 SELECT 
                        ','+QUOTENAME(c.[destfieldname] ) + c.datatype
                 FROM #specnorm c 
                 left join #rawtemp d on c.fieldname = d.fieldname
                 group by c.destfieldname, c.datatype
                 order by min(sourceSequenceTypical) 
                 for xml path ('')),1,1,'')+ ', [sequenceID] int, [subsequenceID] int';


SET @cols1 = STUFF(
             (
                 SELECT 
                        ','+QUOTENAME(c.[destfieldname] )
                 FROM #specnorm c 
                 left join #rawtemp d on c.fieldname = d.fieldname
                 group by c.destfieldname
                 order by min(sourceSequenceTypical) 
                 for xml path ('')),1,1,'')+ ', [sequenceID], 
                 [subsequenceID] ';


 SET @query = ' SELECT '+@cols1+' from (SELECT 
       c.[rownumber],
       c.[contents],
       d.[destfieldname] 
FROM #rawtemp c
left join #specnorm d on c.fieldname = d.fieldname
)x pivot (max(contents) for destfieldname in ('+@cols1+')) p'


exec ('CREATE Table dbo.sample' + ' ('  +@cols + ')');
exec ('Insert into dbo.sample' + @query)
```

Comment: is there any other way then insert (Select ... ) because its taking quite sometime to insert

Comment: i tried to do  Insert into #temp 'SELECT '+@cols+'from but it is giving errors

Comment: i will add the code in my question

Comment: how do i create a table from @cols and insert into the table by using @query?

Comment: sorry i am quite new to this xml tranpose and not really sure on how to do it

Comment: Try the following: `SET @query = 'SELECT '+@cols+' INTO tmp_MyTable from (SELECT `

Comment: @DaleK sorry for that. I have edited my question again. Hope it helps

Comment: @DaleK yes the previous question, i did some mistake in my query, thus i removed it because it worked once i have modified it. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
SET @query = 'SELECT '+@cols+' into YOURTABLE from (SELECT 
   [rownumber],
   [contents],
   [fieldname] 
FROM #rawtemp
) x pivot (max(contents) for fieldname in ('+@cols+')) p'
```

it creates `YOURTABLE` on the fly

Comment: yess it has created but when i try to select * from #temptable, it is saying Invalid object name #temptable

Comment: @Sriram I highly recommend doing so research around SQL server and the things yiu are trying to accomplish. Dynamic SQL runs in a different context to where you call it, consequently any temp tables created within the dynamic context are not available in the calling context.

Comment: yes i understand that. That is the reason why i want to create a new table instead of a temporary one.

Comment: As I asked earlier, what are you **actually** trying to accomplish? What will you do with the data once it's in the temp table? There might be a better solution but we need to know your end goal

Comment: ok actually i am not trying to insert it into a temp table. My goal is to create a dynamic table based on the @cols and then insert the data from #rawtemp into the table created. But i am not sure how to do that.

Comment: @DaleK is the thing i m trying to convey understandable?

Comment: So you wish to end up with a whole bunch of dynamically created tables? What will you do with them then?

Comment: once the table is created, then i can insert the data from #rawtemp to it using @query. This is because the data structure in #rawtemp is vertical and i am trying to convert it to a horizontal using xml transpose. Very sorry because i am new to this

Comment: Right, but you must plan to do this frequently, else you wouldn't be writing a dynamic query... So once you've done this 10 times and have 10 dynamic tables full of data, how will you use it?

Comment: i will update it because data will be keep coming based on the project id but i have not figured it out that yet because my first goal is to insert the data into a new table. So it creates a new table based on every project id

Comment: I have no idea why you have data arriving in this format that you dynamic SQL, nor how you would effectively make use of it once you have a bit much of dynamic SQL tables... I suspect there would be a much better solution if that was understood.

Comment: In order to dynamically create a table you have to dynamically build the create table statement. But you don't really have enough information for that because you don't appear to have the data type of each column available

Comment: i have the datetype and i tried this actually: 'CREATE TABLE NormalizerTmp.dbo.' + t.desttablename  + @tablesuffix  + ' (' + stuff((
    select ',[' + fieldname + '] ' + f.datatype from #specnorm
    where (f.desttablename in (t.desttablename, '*')) 
    group by fieldname, f.datatype 
    order by min(sourceSequenceTypical) 
  for xml path ('')),1,1,'') + ', [sequenceID] int, [subsequenceID] int)'

Comment: but  i m not sure how to put that create table query inside @cols and insert it into a new table. Can you help me on that?

Comment: i am not sure am i explaining correctly. But what i wanted is to create a dynamic table. then do xml tranpose and insert in into the table i have created

Comment: With regard to your dynamic create table statement, as I have asked multiple times now, print the SQL instead of executing it, then you have static SQL to debug and if you still heed help add that to your question.

Comment: You can have 2 statements in your dynamic string, a create table and an insert into table

Comment: @Sriram: You should run `select * from temptable` not `#temptable`. Don't use `#` in your queries